# A prolog predicate checks if an element occurs at least twice in a list

Tags: list, prolog

```
twice(X,[X|Y]):-
   member(X,[Y]).
twice(X,[Y|Z]):-
   twice(X,[Z]),
   X\=Y.
```

I can't find any syntax error,but the execution fails every time.

Comment: `Y` is already a list in `[X|Y]` so you don't want `member(X, [Y])`, and likewise you don't want `member(X, [Z])`!

Comment: since you use member/2, be aware of select/3, that allows for this solution: `twice(X,L) :- select(X,L,R),member(X,R).`

Answer (score 3):

You've got a misconception about the list structure. The list `[H|T]` has head *element* `H` and tail *list* `T`. So `T` is itself a list. If you put `[T]` then that's a list of only one element, that element being the list `T`.

Also, in your second predicate clause, you don't need the `X` argument or to check for `X \= Y` since it's not really relevant if you're checking for *at least* twice.

Thus, your solution changes a little to:

```
twice(X, [X|T]) :-
    member(X, T).
twice(X, [_|T]) :-
    twice(X, T).
```

Which says that *`X` occurs twice in `[X|T]` if `X` is a member of `T`* or *`X` occurs twice in `[_|T]` if `X` occurs twice in `T`*.

Answer (score 3):

I like your intent, but cannot reproduce what you claim: that this predicate fails all the time. In fact, it loops! And here is the fragment why [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
twice(X,[X|Y]):- false,
   member(X,[Y]).
twice(X,[Y|Z]):-
   twice(X,[Z]), false,
   X\=Y

?- twice(a,[a,a]).
```

*Because* this fragment loops, also your original program loops. Lurker has already shown you what is wrong. Here are some alternate formulations:

```
twice(X, Xs) :-
   phrase( ( ..., [X], ..., [X], ... ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Nevertheless, this program has a big flaw:

```
?- twice(a,[a,a,a]).
   true
;  true
;  true
;  false.
```

Thrice the very same answer. One time is more than enough!

The ambiguity comes from the `...`-non-terminal which means just any sequence. There are three ways how that matches the list `[a,a,a]`:

```
     [     a,      a,      a     ]

      ...,[X],...,[X],    ...
      ...,[X],    ...,    [X],...
          ...,    [X],...,[X],...
```

To remove the ambiguity we need to replace the `...` by something more specific. In stead of anything, the sequence should match anything but `X`. In this way only the first match remains.

```
twice(X, Xs) :-
       phrase( ( all(dif(X)), [X], all(dif(X)), [X], ... ), Xs).

all(_) --> [].
all(P_1) -->
   [E],
   {call(P_1,E)},
   all(P_1).

?- twice(a,[a,a,a]).
   true
;  false.
```

That's much better. But is it the bestest? Here is a further improvement using `library(reif)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

twice(C, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(C = X, memberd(X, Xs), twice(C, Xs) ).

memberd(C, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(C = X, true, memberd(C, Xs) ).

?- twice(a,[a,a,a]).
   true.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
twicee(X,[X|Y]):- member(X,Y).
twicee(X,[_|Y]):-twicee(X,Y), X\=Y.
```

Working code for me, check if there are two elements in a list. For example:

```
twicee(X,[a,a,b,b,c,d]).
X = a.
X= b.

twicee(c,[a,a,b,b,d]).
FALSE.
```